# Alignment problem using SVG embedded icon in Navbar bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap provides icons in embedded SVG. These SVG tags can b directly implemented in HTML Code. When I implemented this SVG tag in my navbar, the icon does not appear to be in the middle even though I used vertical-alignment: middle CSS tag. The icon does not appear to be proper. While I used the icon from FontAwesome they appear to be exactly in the middle and appear to be in perfect height and width also. How can I implement SVG tag icons so they appear in the position as it would be done by FOntAwesome Icon[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <title>Unravel-Instilling Hope</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">
            <i>
              <svg style="display:block;" width="2em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-alarm-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 0h4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H9v1.07a7.002 7.002 0 0 1 3.537 12.26l.817.816a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-.924-.925A6.967 6.967 0 0 1 8 16a6.967 6.967 0 0 1-3.722-1.07l-.924.924a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l.817-.816A7.002 7.002 0 0 1 7 2.07V1H5.999a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM.86 5.387A2.5 2.5 0 1 1 4.387 1.86 8.035 8.035 0 0 0 .86 5.387zM13.5 1c-.753 0-1.429.333-1.887.86a8.035 8.035 0 0 1 3.527 3.527A2.5 2.5 0 0 0 13.5 1zm-5 4a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v3.882l-1.447 2.894a.5.5 0 1 0 .894.448l1.5-3A.5.5 0 0 0 8.5 9V5z" />
              </svg>
            </i>
            Download
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check `class="display:block;"` in your HTML... Besides that, not sure how it's styled by default but the space on top probably comes from `display:(inline-)block` and would probably go away with `float`;. You can also reposition your SVG with `position:relative; top:-2px` or whatever number of px is needed to line it up with your text.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. class=" display: block;" was not changing the position of SVG icon. i was wondering why vertical-alignment:middle is not working.When I activated pesticide I found that the SVG icon is aligning at the middle of the anchor tag

Comment: `class=" display: block;"` is invalid HTML. Maybe you meant `style="display: block;"`

Comment: it still didn't work

Comment: It's sill invalid HTML and needs to be fixed. And try `style="position:relative;top:-3px"` to move the SVG up a bit.

Comment: I changed to style=" display:block". The alignment of SVG icon is still not at the center. style="position:relative;top:-3px" this works but I wanted to know why it is not at the middle automatically with the vertical-alignment: middle.

Comment: Please put the css file.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap and home.css is file is empty while I will use in future to style content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `display: flex; align-items: center;` to `.nav-link`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Unravel-Instilling Hope</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="" style="display: flex;
align-items: center;">
            <i>
            <svg style="display:block;" width="2em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-alarm-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 0h4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H9v1.07a7.002 7.002 0 0 1 3.537 12.26l.817.816a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-.924-.925A6.967 6.967 0 0 1 8 16a6.967 6.967 0 0 1-3.722-1.07l-.924.924a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l.817-.816A7.002 7.002 0 0 1 7 2.07V1H5.999a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM.86 5.387A2.5 2.5 0 1 1 4.387 1.86 8.035 8.035 0 0 0 .86 5.387zM13.5 1c-.753 0-1.429.333-1.887.86a8.035 8.035 0 0 1 3.527 3.527A2.5 2.5 0 0 0 13.5 1zm-5 4a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v3.882l-1.447 2.894a.5.5 0 1 0 .894.448l1.5-3A.5.5 0 0 0 8.5 9V5z" />
            </svg>
          </i> Download
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest using the classes `d-flex align-items-center` instead of using inline CSS, but that could be a matter of taste. Furthermore I found out that the `style="display:  block"` was also important to make it work.